# Selection of Linked Selections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I am using the [React + Redux + Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-router) stack and by this time I have got a simple React component where I am trying to develop a selection of linked selection with [this](http://jspears.github.io/subschema/#/CarMake) behavior example.

In fact my component can easily consume this variable:

```
var VAR_OPTIONS_OLD = [
    {value: 1, name: '1'},
    {value: 2, name: '2'},
    {value: 3, name: '3'},
    {value: 4, name: '4'},
    {value: 5, name: '5'},
]
```

Where the component is this one:

```
<Field
      type={Select}
      options={VAR_OPTIONS_OLD}
      optionValue="value"
      id="someID"
      class="col-12"
      i18n={i18n.someID}
/>
```

Now I want my both selects consume this variable:

```
var VAR_OPTIONS_NEW = {
    optionA: {
        name: 'Option A',
        suboption: ['Suboption A1', 'Suboption A2', 'Suboption A3']
    },
    optionB: {
        name: 'Option B',
        suboption: ['Suboption B1', 'Suboption B2', 'Suboption B3']
    },
    optionC: {
        name: 'Option C',
        suboption: ['Suboption C1', 'Suboption C2', 'Suboption C3']
    }
}
```

So that I can take advantage of having 2 linked selects depending each other.

Source: [Var Container Example Gist](https://gist.github.com/FMCalisto/c06f65efbc4d9c251b5e7f5bc4ae8e96)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **view component code**:

At top:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const VAR_OPTIONS_NEW = ... // The one you provided.
```

in *render():*

```
const firstValue = ... // this should come from your Store (e.g. this.props.firstValue).
const secondValue = ... // this should come from a Store

const firstOptions = _.map(VAR_OPTIONS_NEW, (v, k) => ({ value: k, name: v.name });

let secondOptions = [];
if (VAR_OPTIONS_NEW[firstValue]) {
    secondOptions = VAR_OPTIONS_NEW[firstValue].suboptions.map(
        (name, index) => ({ value: index, name: name })
    );
}
...
<Field
    options={ firstOptions }
    optionsValue={ firstValue }
    onChange={/* is your onChange event connected to Store? */}
    ...
/>
<Field
    options={ secondOptions }
    optionsValue={ secondValue }
    onChange={/* is your onChange event connected to Store? */}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Is there any solution without getting into the Store?

Comment: You could add the `firstValue` and `secondValue` to the Components state. [Similar to this](http://pastebin.com/0PvfYq8f) ← Note: I only wrote this code in a form field. Haven't tested it. It may contain syntax and other kinds of errors.

Comment: How can I put `firstValue` and `secondValue` on the `Store`?

Comment: I also add the link:

https://gist.github.com/FMCalisto/c06f65efbc4d9c251b5e7f5bc4ae8e96

Comment: How can I transfer `firstValue` and `secondValue` props from `Store`?